# How to add row in another form if running in mainForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've tried this code to add a row of function that I created on the main form (Form1) in DataGridView in Form2, but there is no result add row  when I run its function, does anyone know where the mistake?
Thanks

[edit]Code in MainForm1 :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 sub = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sub.AddRow(new string[] { "1", "2" }); // able to loop
        sub.Show();
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

[edit] Code in Form2 :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void AddRow(string[] values)
    {
        this.DGVFile.Rows.Add(values);
    }
}
```

I get a few hints at some answers. My questions were answered when the data is loaded in datagridview in Form2 and also I want the mainform (Form1) can be disabled when opening Form2. Now it has been resolved. Thanks All.

Comment: Take the creation of the second form from the button click event out: `Form2 sub = new Form2();`, so that the form is created only once. Then use show and hide methods if needed and create an extra method to add new row to the existing form / control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub.Show();` instead. This way, the code bellow `sub.ShowDialog();` will not even get called.

`ShowDialog` opens a new form as a modal window, which means, that the focus is only in the new window and lines below this call are called when the new windows is closed.

You can find more information about these two methods on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

> but i want disabled mainform if open form2

I can think of two options.

The first, and in my opinion better, is to postopne opening of the form

```
Form2 sub = new Form2();
sub.RegisterParent(this);
for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++ )
{
    string[] row;
    row = new string[] { "1","2"};
    sub.DGVFile.Rows.Add(row);
}
sub.ShowDialog(); // open when everything is prepared
```

The second is

```
sub.Show();
this.Enabled = false;
```

but this is not really a nice solution, because you would have to enable it from the other form before closing it and there are many ways how to close a form and you would have to consider all.

Comment: you're right, but i want disabled mainform if open form2. i have tried this. if (sub.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) , but not add the row. where the mistake?

Comment: Nice solution. I've tried it. Now i try to change 'enabled = false' to 'enabled = true' in Form2. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the creation of the second form from the button click event out: `Form2 sub = new Form2();`. This way the second form is created only once. Then use `ShowDialog` and `Hide` methods to show a modal second form (the first form will be inactive). Create an extra public method in the second form to add new row to the existing DataGridView.

A possible solution can look like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private DataForm dataForm = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // init data form
        dataForm = new DataForm();
        dataForm.Init();
    }

    private void buttonAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add values
        dataForm.AddRow(new string[] { "10", "20" });
        // show a modal second form, so that the first can not be selected while the second is open!
        dataForm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}

public partial class DataForm : Form
{
    public DataForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // init the grid
    internal void Init()
    {
        this.dataGridView.Columns.Add("A", "A");
        this.dataGridView.Columns.Add("B", "B");
        for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
        {
            string[] row;
            row = new string[] { "1", x.ToString() };
            this.dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }
    // add values to the grid
    public void AddRow(string[] values)
    {
        this.dataGridView.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    // hide second form
    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Output after two additions is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @pasty ,  This code is very helpful, but here I tried if there was a method in Form1 :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with `if there was a method`?

Comment: i try when my method looping 'for' in mainForm. But i've tried this code. Thanks @pasty.

Comment: You could move the for-loop in the MainForm, button click event, and use the DataForm.AddRow method to add values in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code after `sub.ShowDialog();` is executed only after the form sub is closed. Try using `sub.Show()`

Comment: you're right, but i want disabled mainform if open form2. how it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following code:

```
namespace TEST_CSA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 sub = new Form2();
            sub.Show(this);
            this.Enabled = false;
            sub.RegisterParent(this);
            for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
            {
                string[] row;
                row = new string[] { "1", "2" };
                sub.DGVFile.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The command `Show(this)` makes Form1 the parent form of Form2 and also ensures that Form2 will be always displayed on top of Form1. To deactivate Form1 use `this.Enabled = false;` In order to reactivate Form1 when Form2 closes use the following code:

```
namespace TEST_CSA
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private Form1 _parent;
        internal void RegisterParent(Form1 form)
        {
            this._parent = form;
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            _parent.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
}
```